# Aptana 3.2.2 preview does not open internal browser (ubuntu 12.10 64 bits)

Tags: aptana, ubuntu-12.04, aptana3, xulrunner

After installing Aptana Studio3 (version 3.3.2)  in my Ubuntu 12.10 I find out that the preview button did not work properly. Meaning, I was not able to see the preview in the opened tab. As if internal browser was not working.
[image]

Instead of that , I obtained a copy of my index.html which is the doc I am trying to preview.
[image]

I find out that Xulrunner was not instaled in my system and therefore I suspect this could be the issue.

Downloaded XULrunner version required by Aptana, with

wget -O xulrunner.deb http://launchpadlibrarian.net/70321329/xulrunner-1.9.2_1.9.2.17%2Bbuild3%2Bnobinonly-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

But when I tried to install this package I obtained a dependency error asking for ibhunspell-1.2-0

```
xulrunner-1.9.2 depends on libhunspell-1.2-0
```

I will appreciate your help to put some light over this issue.
Am I missing something/s here?

Eventually, suggest where to obtain  the missing package (libhunspell-1.2-0  ppa or whatever reliable source) and any specific  installing instructions if necessary.

Many thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Packages installed but problem remains.
I obtained the  libhunspell-1.2-0_1.2.11-1_amd64.deb from  [debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/libhunspell-1.2-0/download)
Once succesfully installed  I proceed to install the xulrunner.deb
Everything Ok as well!
Now they are all there...but... Internal browser still doesn`t work

If anybody from Aptana or with any experience about this matter, is in the neighborhood , please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is a reported issue of Aptana 3.2.2** (actual version March 2013)

**Solution**: revert to 3.2.x version or wait until 3.4.x is available (where is already fixed)

**Detailed Info**

After several checkings and research , I find out that there is a reported issue with the actual version 3.3.2

**Issue labeled as:**

> Aptana Studio     APSTUD-7636 
>   **Cannot show preview (embedded WebKit browser)**

This can be seen here at  [appcelerator issue tracker](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7636) where states the following

> **Expected Result:**
>
> Preview should be opened exactly as in previous versions of Aptana. Preview worked without errors in Aptana 3.2.X before updating to 3.3.1.

This was corrected for version  3.3.4 which at present (march 2013) I am not able to obtain. So I reverted to  3.2.2  which I downloaded from [appacelerator wiki](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version#RevertingtoaPreviousVersion-AptanaStudio3.2.2)

Full package name: **Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_64_3.2.2.zip**

**I installed and  the preview is working as it should**

So: Until version 3.4.x is not available ill keep this old one 3.2.2
I hope that my research will be useful to someone else.

Comment: Titanium may be affected as well and same solution may apply as well